# Open specific link in new tab or window on link clicking

Tags: hyperlink, tabs, new-operator

I have a wallpaper website. This website include a lot of wallpapers with variety of resolution links.

I would like to do that if someone click on a wallpaper and he chose his best resolution (clicked on the resolution link) open a new tab with a specified url link. Can some help me with a script code please?

Comment: Can you please share bit of your code?

Comment: I have no code for it, I wish I could have

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the link's [target attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

```
<a href="some link" target="_blank">Link text</a>
```

Comment: Not really. See this example: https://grabwallpapers.com/wallpaper/mobile-stock-wallpapers/poco-x2-stock-wallpapers-16/An3P there are available resolutions of wallpaper. for example 10204 x 768 i want to do that if someone click on this resolution, open a new tab with specified link